# Using sinon for axios.put or post

Tags: reactjs, sinon

Does anyone know a link or reference where I can find a sample sinon test for axios.put or post?
Currently I'm working on react js and I want to try to test my axios.put or post using sinon mocking. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
const MyService = {
  save: body => axios.post('/save', body).then(response => Promise.resolve(response.data))  
}

describe('MyService save', () => {

  it('should parse and return the response data', () => {

    const stubBody = { nic: 'cage' }
    const stubResponse = {status: 200, statusText: 'OK', data: { oscars: 1 } }
    const stubPost = sinon.stub(axios, 'post').withArgs('/save', stubBody).returns(Promise.resolve(stubResponse))

    expect(MyService.save(stubBody)).to.eventually.satisfy(_ => _.oscars === 1)
    stubPost.restore()

  })

})
```